# Send Parent ViewController value to UICollectionViewCell cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have the following scenario and was wondering how I can resolve this issue of sending a parent `UIViewController` value to the `UICollectionView` cell.

1) Parent `UIViewController` renders `UICollectionView`

2) `UICollectionViewCell` has dynamic generated `UILabel` with (`UITapGestureRecognizer`) target attached

3) On `UITapGestureRecognizer` it triggers an action to tell the Parent `UIViewController` to present a Popup `UIViewController`

4) Popup `ViewController` has a `UITable` with a few options to select

5) Upon selection, Popup `ViewController` is dismissed

I can get the value but how can I pass the value from the Parent `UIViewController` back to the `UICollectionViewCell` cell?

Comment: I would use delegation for this.

Comment: Any examples or links?

Answer (score 0):

You need to access your cell like this:

```
if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? yourCollectionViewCell { 
    cell.yourValue = yourNextValue
}
```

If you need to do any UI updates after this, you may need to call `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` methods.

Comment: How can I get the UILabel at that cell then set its text property? My UILabel's are rendered dynamically so I need to reference the right UILabel and set the value

Comment: Can you share how do you render your `UILabels`, because without this info, I cannot help you.